# $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb C$ holomorphic, $D$ a convex set, $Re(f'(z))>0$. Prove that $f$ is injective

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$f:D \rightarrow \mathbb C$ holomorphic, $D$ a convex set, $Re(f'(z))>0$. Prove that $f$ is injective.

What I tried: Assume that $f$ is not injective. So there are $a,b \in D$ so that $f(a)=f(b)$.

So we get that:

$\int_a^bf'(z)dz=f(a)-f(b)=0 $

How do I use the fact that $Re(f'(z))>0$? Or that's not the direction at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost done! The idea is there.. You need to fill in the details though;

Let $a, b$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$.

Let $\gamma(t) =  a(1-t) + tb$ ($\gamma$ is the straight line going from $a$ to $b$)

Since our set $D$ is convex, we know that $\gamma(t)$ lies in $D$.

Take $F(t) = f(\gamma(t))$. Then $F'(t) = f'(\gamma(t))(b-a)$

Now consider $\int_0^1 F'(t) \ dt = f(\gamma(1)) - f(\gamma(0)) = f(b) - f(a) = 0$

But $\int_0^1 F'(t) = \int_0^1 \Re(F'(t)) + i \int_0^1 \Im(F'(t)) = 0$ that would imply $\int_0^1 \Re(F'(t)) = 0$ but that is impossible as $\Re (F'(t)) > 0$ by hypothesis